# Priority Queue - When Prioritizing Take Place?

Tags: data-structures

In a Priority Queue we first enqueue according to the priority given to the element? Or we enqueue just like a queue but dequeue high the highest priority element first?
Or both ways are acceptable?

Comment: Either way will work; there might be differences in performance depending on how one does the implementation. Can you see how that might be a factor? Pick a couple of implementations and try each. By the way, good question.

Comment: Naive theoretical answer: both can work. Practical answer: priority queues are almost-always implemented using a heap, which doesn't really look like a queue and is actually a particular kind of binary tree with the property that the highest-priority element is always at the root.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a priority queue is to get the elements by decreasing priority when they are initially unordered. So your first hypothesis does not hold.

(Of course you could enqueue in priority order, but then the queue can just be a FIFO.)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data structure is usually a heap, and the elements are partially ordered when it's initialized. At that point, the highest priority element is at the root of the heap ready to be popped next. When a new element is added to the heap it is added at the end and partial ordering is done bottom up; and when an element is removed the last element moved to the root and the partial ordering is done top down. So when implemented using a heap, the prioritization is maintained by partial ordering when initialized and when an element is added or removed.

Comment: There's also other data structures that can be used but I think heaps are the most common approach.